# Batch Encoder Program Error

Tags: debugging, batch-file, encryption

***Purpose***

I'm working on a project that encrypts a message. It first asks for input. Then it reverses the string. Then, it replaces each letter of the string with a different symbol. After the encryption is done, it copies to clipboard.
For example: Shodisi Nutzu >> uztuN isidohS >> `!@`# *$*(&^$
This is the code I have so far.

**Asks For Input**

```
    set /p advanced="Input- "
```

**Reverse String**

```
    set string1=
    set num=0
    :LOOP
    call set tmpa=%%advanced:~%num%,1%%%
    set /a num+=1
    if defined tmpa (
        set rline=%tmpa%%rline%
        goto :LOOP
    )
```

**Replace Letters**

```
    set a=` && set b=@ && set c=# && set d=$ && set e=* && set f=( && set g=) && set h=_ && set i=¯ && set j=+ && set k== && set l=[ && set m=] && set n={ && set o=} && set p=\ && set q=/ && set r=; && set s=: && set t=? && set u=~ && set v=° && set w=¶ && set x=ò && set y=ò && set z=ö
    set rline=%rline:a=!a!%
    set rline=%rline:b=!b!%
    set rline=%rline:c=!c!%
    set rline=%rline:d=!d!%
    set rline=%rline:e=!e!%
    set rline=%rline:f=!f!%
    set rline=%rline:g=!g!%
    ===You Get The Pattern===
    set rline=%rline:x=!x!%
    set rline=%rline:y=!y!%
    set rline=%rline:z=!z!%
    set rline=%rline: =-%
```

**Copy To Clipboard**

```
    echo %rline%| clip
```

It seems like everything is going smooth but the replacing letters part sometimes gives the first word reversed and replaced. How do I fix this? I know that this code is all over the place, so how can I condense it too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's unicode characters in the code

Comment: You've tagged this with syntax-error, yet not given any error message. You state the reverse encryption doesn't work, yet don't show that code. How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: Sorry I fixed this. I was unclear the last time about what I _actually_ need.

Comment: Dark Fang, yes the unicode is actually compatible because I tested letter by letter and there is no syntax error for any.

Comment: **1**. `set a=' && set b=@ && set c=# && ...` adds a trailing space to every variable value, e.g. `echo "%b%"` displays `"@ "`. **2**. I don't see `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`. **3**. I think that right replace syntax is `set rline=!rline:a=%a%!`

Comment: So how do I prevent the space for being made?